# What damage is possible due to hyperextension?

Tags: injury

I found [a page](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/hyperextended-knee/AN00283) that lists ligament and cartilage damage, but is it possible that the hyperextension of a joint can leave bone fragments in the joint?

Comment: This sounds like a self-diagnosis question, in which case it would be a really good idea to go see a doctor about it as quickly as possible. Beyond that I think the answer is "anything's possible, but not everything is likely".

Comment: Welcome @Michael, your question doesn't tell us what happened or what's wrong with your knee. However, as @jprete mentions, if you drew this conclusion yourself, you'd better go see a doctor. We're not here to make a diagnosis. Either way, if bone fragments had broken off, I'm sure you'd be in so much pain that you'd had to go to the hospital.

Comment: @Ivo Elbow, not knee, but you might be right about the pain.  It was definitely uncomfortable, but not "broken bone" painful. :P

Comment: I think this question should be closed as it is not about injury prevention but medical advice, see the [FAQ] as well.

Comment: This would be a better question if it related more to a specific exercise or movement rather than just general information. Michael, please feel free to edit it and make it on-topic as outlined in our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

Hyperextension is a frequent cause of bone bruises.  These are very long and painful injuries that disrupt the surface of the bone (they're more like many micro-fractures as opposed to a bruise).

See http://www.beyondprinting.com/sportsmed/PDF/thurs/MRI_TH_06.pdf for some more information on the relationship between bone bruises and hyperextension (it also includes bone bruise causes other than hyperextension).